# How to trace a MAC address on a switched LAN?

Tags: mac-address, layer2

How to trace a MAC address on a switched LAN?

I want to be able to find out a switch port's MAC address.

- No device uses IP, therefore no address resolution and no SNMP.
- No device runs CDP, therefore no Cisco L2 traceroute.
- No fancy tools on my laptop available.

Topology: There are 10 switches. One is in the center. It is connected to four other switches. Each of those four switches is connected to another switch. Each switch in the third row has three end devices attached. All devices are connected via switching port, except end devices which use their NIC. I cannot change the topology. But I can hang on to whatever device I want and change its configuration as far as I do not assign an IP address to a switch or enable CDP.

Firmware: Cisco Catalyst 2950-24 IOS C2950-I6Q4L2-M 12.1(22)EA4. That's the one Packet Tracer simulates.

Yes, I did read the question *Locate a host on Network*. This question may be answered with a simple no.

Comment: Your search-foo is lacking... look through the mac-address table of each switch to trace back where a specific machine lives. (i.e. look at the table on every "edge" switch)

Comment: @Ricky_Beam: Thank for your advice - haven't considered that yet! Definitely a more efficient approach. /// Cisco Catalyst 2950-24 IOS C2950-I6Q4L2-M 12.1(22)EA4. That's the one Packet Tracer simulates. /// This question may be answered with a simple no.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you're asking for when you say "_I want to be able to find out a switch port's MAC address._" Do you want to know the MAC address of the switchport itself?  Or of a device connected to a particular switchport.

Comment: @Brett_Lykins : I want to follow every MAC address on the LAN. I would like to trace a MAC as simple as an IP traceroute. However, I know that is implossible. I prefer **pyatka**'s approach because it's the most efficient one.

Comment: @user2964971 when you say _"No device uses IP"_, do you mean you don't have the IP addresses on hand?

Comment: There is no switch with an IP. Only PC's.

Comment: @user2964971 if the switches do not have IP addresses, how are you accessing them for management, console connection at each switch?

Comment: I was forbidden to leave the project with any switch having an IP address. I was allowed to reset switches and configure them temporarily however I wanted. I could connect via console port. I did post the question because I wanted to know _How to trace a MAC address on a switched LAN_ under these constraints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an [end-to-end vlan topology](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/21137), where vlans are not terminated on switches, you can use somethink like this algorithm:

On the root switch get the mac address table, use filter output:

```
sh mac add | i 8a06

1    0015.5d02.8a06   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other TenGigabitEthernet4/5
```

Now you know, that mac is behind interface TenGigabitEthernet4/5. Connect to the switch behind this interface, and repeat `sh mac add | i 8a06`. You will find your host in the end.

Answer (score 0):

in layer 3 you can use the below:

show mac-address table address i 5840.85128.sc48

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of device ip address then we can process commands to get mac -address

In layer3 devices enter command

Assuming your device ip address is 192.168.X.X

`Switch (config)#sh ip arp | I 192 .168.X.X`

`Output of command = mac address for specific ip address is showen`

`So further even we can find on which L2 interface this end device is connected by using commend`

`Layer3 device =Switch(config) # sh mac -address table | I aea.24a.xxx xxx.xx`

Comment: The question explicitly states “No devices use IP”

Comment: If no devices uses ip mean you cannot trace devices

Comment: I think you’re confusing tracing (finding out on which port a mac address is used) with the utility called traceroute.