# How to trace the MAC route?

Tags: switch, mac

If there have several Switches, they are connected using trunk, and in the end switch there is server on it.

So, if there is a controller server on the other end.

if the controller trace to the end servers, there should go through several switches, so, is there any protocol for trace MAC addresses(compare to the `traceroute` cmd for IP route)?

before ask this question, I searched this [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5823/how-to-trace-a-mac-address-on-a-switched-lan), but this is not my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching works on the data link layer (L2) and in contrast to L3, there are no concepts like TTL or ICMP on L2. Therefore, a tool like IP traceroute cannot exist.

The best way to trace a potential L2 path across multiple switches is to examine their MAC tables. Each frame will exit the switch through the port associated with the frame's destination MAC address (on the according VLAN).

There are various tools using SNMP to extract the MAC tables of multiple switches and use those to calculate a frame's path - product recommendations are off-topic here, however.